# JQuery Code Duplication for AJAX Calls

Tags: javascript, jquery

Original AJAX code with no JQuery. Note the definition of `someVar` at the very beginning.

```
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (req.readyState == 4) {
                        //CODE HERE
                        var someVar = ....
                        //method() should be called when AJAX call returns
                        someVar.method();
                        if (req.status != 200) {
                            // error code
                                someVar.doSomething();
                        } else if (req.responseText) {
                            //other code
                                someVar.doSomethingElse();
                        } 
                    }
                };
                req.send(null);
```

My best attempt at JQuery. Note the code duplication:

```
$.get(url)
    .done(function(data){
        var someVar = ....
        someVar.method();
        someVar.doSomethingElse();
    })
    .fail(function(){
        var someVar = ...
        someVar.method();
        someVar.doSomething();
    });
```

Is there anyway to run code BEFORE `done` and `fail` (which is why `always` doesnt work in this case)?

Comment: why can't you just use always and test the status code the same way you did before? (hint: the second argument is the textStatus)

Comment: @KevinB that's totally not the same thing, he wants to share someVar between .done and .fail

Comment: @KevinB because it's uglier - and Bubbles provided a more reasonable solution.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Sure it is the same thing as what i'm comparing it to.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum And Bubbles answer actually does what i'm suggesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) documentation, `done`, `fail`, `always` and `then` should be invoked in the order they are registered - have you tried putting the shared code in an `always` before the other functions?

[Here's](http://jsbin.com/ihIVUPOr/1/) a jsBin showing this in action; just be sure to leave the console open.

---

**EDIT**

This is a bit gimmicky, but if you're *really* deadset on not having a variable in the parent scope, there is some degree of shared context between the functions you can use. A jQuery ajax request is it's own object, and as such you can share data on this object between calls on it.

So, you could share the code like so:

```
$.get()
  .always(function() {
    this.someVar = ...
    this.someVar.doMethod();
  }).done(function() {
    this.someVar.doneFunction();
  }).fail(function() {
    this.someVar.failFunction();
  })
```

If you were to do this though, I'd be a bit more cautious with my variable conventions - probably would try to prefix `someVar` with something application-specific (like `myApp_someVar`).

Comment: How is this going to help me share the variable `someVar` between the other two promised methods exactly though? See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aqS9P/

Comment: @thatidiotguy that's only possible by storing the variable in a scope that's available to all three callbacks (such as the parent scope). If you want to avoid that, you'll have to do all of the logic within one always callback.

Comment: @KevinB That's what it seems like. I like the new promises, but this does seem like a minor issue with that system. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Is it that bad to share the parent scope here? Personally, I don't see this as being particularly bad form - http://jsfiddle.net/aqS9P/1/, but opinions may vary.

Comment: @thatidiotguy I updated my answer with something that may be more to your taste.

Comment: @Bubbles One of the problems is that I want to assign the variable as close to the return response as possible, as the value of `someVar` could theoretically be different (b/c of user input) in between the request going out, and the response coming back. 
It does seem the using the parent scope is the only to take care of this. Thanks for your answer!